# ERROR Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path python pycharm

Tags: python, pyspark

I try start simple app with spark. I downloaded spark - "pip install spark. And  now when I try to run my code error occurs:

> ERROR Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary
>   path java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable
>   null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:379)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:394)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.(Shell.java:387)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.(StringUtils.java:80)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.getAuthenticationMethod(SecurityUtil.java:611)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:273)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:791)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:761)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:634)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2422)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2422)
>     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2422)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SecurityManager.(SecurityManager.scala:79)     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.secMgr$lzycompute$1(SparkSubmit.scala:359)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$secMgr$1(SparkSubmit.scala:359)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$7.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:367)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$7.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:367)
>     at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)   at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:366)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:143)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
>   19/05/13 22:57:18 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop
>   library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where
>   applicable Using Spark's default log4j profile:
>   org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties Setting default log level
>   to "WARN". To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For
>   SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).

Well, I downloaded winutils.exe, created "c:\winutils\bin" and copied winutils. Also created environment path HADOOP_HOME. But I can't understand why it does not work. 
My code

```
from pyspark.shell import sc
os.environ ['HADOOP_HOME']= "C:\\winutils"

lines = sc.textFile("ob.txt")
pythonLines = lines .filter(lambda line: "python" in line)
print(pythonLines)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few steps you should have: (for Hadoop and Spark)

- Add winutils.exe to SPARK_HOME/bin
- hadoop.dll and winutils.exe in HADOOP_HOME/bin
- Add to system paths: %HADOOP_HOME%\bin and %SPARK_HOME%\bin

Try using findspark (https://github.com/minrk/findspark) and run this as a test:

```
import findspark
findspark.init("C:\Spark\spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7") #wherever your Spark directory is
import pyspark # only run after findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.sql('''select 'spark' as hello ''')
```